# How to ensure data consistency across multiple related tables with concurrent queries

Tags: sql, database, concurrency, transactions, consistency

So, my data model is similar to an assignment problem. So, let's assume we have a firm that provides suitable workers for requested jobs.

For now, I have such relations:

- `Customer` (id)
- `Job` (id)
- `Worker` (id, available)
- `Jobs In Progress` (customer_id, job_id)
- `Busy Workers` (customer_id, worker_id)

There are many-to-many between `Customer` and `Job` and many-to-many between `Customer` and `Worker`. This data is like real-time, so it's highly dynamic.

We want to maintain such queries:

1. Request a worker for a job.
2. Return the worker when the job has finished.

This queries requires to read, update, delete and insert data in several tables.

For example, if customer requests for a worker, we have to check whether this customer already exists in the table; whether he already owns a suitable worker in `Busy Workers`; if no, find a suitable available worker in `Worker`; check whether such a job already registered in `Job`. And in the worst case, we have to atomically insert customer in `Customer`, insert job in `Job`, insert a corresponding row in `Jobs In Progress`, decrement `Worker.avaiable` and insert a row in `Busy Workers`.

In the second query, we have to do all of this stuff in a reversed order: increment `Worker.available`, delete the customer if he has no jobs, delete the job if no one customer needs it and so on.

So we have a lot of consistency rules: number of busy workers have to be consistent with `Worker.available`, a customer has to be present in the table only if he has requested not finished jobs, a job has to be present in the table only if there are no customers with such a job requested.

I read a lot about isolations levels and locking in databases, but I still don't understand how to ensure consistency across multiple tables. It seems like isolation levels don't work because multiple tables are involved and data may become inconsistent between select from two tables. And it seems like locks don't work too, because AFAIK SQL Server can't atomically acquire a lock on multiple tables and therefore data may become inconsistent between locks.

And, actually, I'm looking for a solution or idea of a solution in general, without referencing to a concrete RDBMS, it should be something that applicable one way or another to the most famous RDBMS's like MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and Oracle. So it does not have to be a proper solution with examples with all of this RDMS's, maybe some practices, tips or 
references.

I apologize for my English and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is really too broad.  You want to store data in one place, use triggers if you need to keep things updated, and calculate values when you need them.  Designing an entire reservation and allocation system is a big task.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, I think my question can be simplified to "How to ensure consistency across 2 related tables". I believe, that if I can do stuff with 2 tables then I can spread it to `n` tables. But I don't even know what to do in case of 2 tables. There are still problems with isolation and locks that I described in the question. But I can go wrong and my understanding of isolations and locks can be wrong and I'm pretty sure that I am because concurrent access to multiple tables is not so rare task I guess.

Answer (score 0):

First: Think about your model a bit more. I would not keep so much redundant information. "decrement Worker.avaiable and insert a row in Busy Workers" are completely superfluous because you can get the information easily by asking the other tables. You might say that is more costly to query. That I would call premature optimization. Redundancy is very costly per se.

Second: Think of locks as exclusive resources that only one may get. So the most simple way to ensure consistency would be to let all dbms-users lock just one record in the database using *select ... for update*. All changes would be serialized. If you use a MVCC-Dbms like postgres, oracle or even sql-server, the readers would always see a consistent situation.

Third: Doing your change perhaps you just need to detect, if another user/transaction already changed a certain record. This can be done by maintaining, so called, version-attributes and checking during updates, if those attributes where changed. If a change was detected, you have to repeat the complete transaction. That is called optimistic locking.

Fourth or better the most important point: I hope you understood the concept of dbms-transaction as a means to bring a dbms from one consistent state to the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
First: I thought about it, but it looks for me that it will be more difficult to control concurrency this way, but maybe I'm wrong. I'll think again.
Second: Yes, at this moment I try to implement this using `for update`. It causes deadlocks, but, anyway, I think I'll fix it.
Third: I'll think about it too. I thought about Timestamp Ordering, but it didn't look applicable for my case, maybe with new knowledge I'll change my mind.